# Parameters filled with nothing gets anyhow filled?

Tags: javascript, ajax

I'm taking a javascript course but can´t get my head around how my example below have the parameter being populated with the "correct stuff" since there is nowhere I actually call the function with a corresponding element?

```
  success: function(result) {
    $('myElement').html(result);
  }
```

Guess that there must be some sort of default behaviour going on that I've missed?

Hope someone can help me get this straight.
/Kristofer Guldvarg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets simplify how jQuery is defined (the *very* curious can see the actual AJAX implementation [here](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/ajax.js));

```
var jQuery = {
    ajax: function (obj) {
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

        xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
            if (this.readyState === 4 && this.status === 200) {
                obj.success(this.textContent);
            }
        }

        xhr.open(obj.url, 'GET', false);
        xhr.send(null);
    }
};
```

When you do;

```
jQuery.ajax({
    url: '/foo.php',
    success: function (response) {
        $('myElement').html(result);
    }
});
```

.. jQuery can *call* the success function using `obj.success`, and *pass* it whatever data it wants (in this case `this.textContent`).

You're not *calling* the function; you're defining a function, and passing it to *somewhere else*, and allowing them to call it later, and pass the information they want to.

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a callback. So another function is responsible for calling it at some point and passing `result`.

So you are calling a function that takes a `success` function. You are saying "Hey, when you're done with that, please call this success function that I have given you and please give IT the `result` that you've come up with.

Answer (score 0):

It's a [Callback](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Callback_%28computer_programming%29#JavaScript) function implemented as a [Closure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_%28computer_science%29).